How to send messages to an XMPP server using only Twisted?
I need to send messages to an XMPP server. Only send - I don't need to process replies, make a bot, or anything like that. When using the xmpppy module, it goes something like this:
from xmpp import Client
from xmpp.protocol import JID, Message


jabberid = 'user@server.com'
password = 'secret'
receiver = 'sender_id@conference.server.com'
message = 'Hello world!'

jid = JID(jabberid)
connection = Client(server=jid.getDomain(), debug=None)
connection.connect()
connection.auth(user=jid.getNode(), password=password, resource=jid.getResource())
connection.send(Message(to=receiver, body=message))

However, I need to do this using Twisted. Unfortunately, the documentation is mostly useless (seems machine-generated) and I have absolutely no idea what I am supposed to do. :-(
Maybe something like
from twisted.words.protocols.jabber.jid import JID
from twisted.words.protocols.jabber.client import XMPPAuthenticator

jabberid = 'user@server.com'
password = 'secret'

jid = JID(jabberid)
XMPPAuthenticator(jid, password)

but what then?

From https://twisted.org/ click the "View Document" button, then choose "Twisted Words (IRC and XMPP)" from the index on the left, then choose "Examples" on the resulting page, then download the xmpp_client.py example.
In this example, you'll see how to use the reactor to make your client connect to a server, how to use the bootstrap APIs to handle basic connection management events, and how to do basic presence management.
After that, it depends what kind of messages you want to send (presence is managed by sending messages, for example).  If you want to send a XEP-0045 "groupchat" message, such as is described at https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#message, construct one using the xish APIs and send it instead of or along with your presence message.
If you want to send a message like:
<message
    to='romeo@example.net'
    from='juliet@example.com/balcony'
    type='chat'
    xml:lang='en'>
  <body>Wherefore art thou, Romeo?</body>
</message>

which I'm guessing is what this line from your question does:
connection.send(Message(to=receiver, body=message))

Then you can do something like:
from twisted.words.xish import domish

message = domish.Element((None, 'message'))
message['to'] = 'user@example.com'
message.addElement('body', content='Hi!')

This is adapted from an example in the documentation.
Then you can send the message after your client authenticates.  If you modify the xmpp_client.py example by replacing the authenticated method with this one:
    def authenticated(self, xs):
        print("Authenticated.")

        message = domish.Element((None, 'message'))
        message['to'] = 'user@example.com'
        message.addElement('body', content='Hi!')
        xs.send(message)

        self.reactor.callLater(5, xs.sendFooter)


How does one actually send messages with that example? It seems to just connect, authenticate, and wait until disconnected, while logging the traffic. Furthermore, while using the very same server and credentials that work just fine in xmpppy, I get the error [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>: [('system library', '', ''), ('STORE routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('system library', '', ''), ('STORE routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('system library', '', ''), ('STORE routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('SSL routines', '', 'certificate verify failed')].

XMPP is nothing but a huge mountain of messages.  Can you be more specific about what kind of message you want to send, and when?  As for the OpenSSL error, check out the Twisted TLS docs for information about how to control certificate verification (or open a new question, it's too difficult to answer that in comments).

I don't want to disable certificate validation. Looking at the site (movim.eu), it's has a Let's Encrypt certificate that looks just fine. Why does xmppp work with it but Twisted doesn't? As for the kind of message I want to send - I gave an example of what I want to do using the xmppp module. How can I do the equivalent using Twisted?

I didn't write "disable", I wrote "control".  There are a bunch of docs that I won't try to reproduce in a comment on an answer to a question that's not about obviously TLS.  Please have a look at https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/core/howto/ssl.html and open a new question about it if something's not clear.

I edited the answer to give an example of building and sending a message like the one in the question.

I'm afraid I really don't understand what I should control about the TLS. Like, why does the connection fail, what is wrong with the certificate, and what to do about it? On that page you linked to, if I try the check_server_certificate.py script, it fails immediately with an error that host.decode("utf-8") can't be done on a str. If I remove the .decode part, it says "BAD" for every site, including www.twistedmatrix.com.

Thanks for editing the example, this helps. However, wouldn't it send the message only once, after authenticating to the server? What if I want to send another message later? Is there some other method, besides authenticated in the class Client that I should implement and call?

Yes, it will only send the message once after authentication.  The pattern for sending messages at other times is similar, but you have to define what those times are.  Twisted is event-driven.  You will probably need to hook up your message sending logic to respond to some event.  That event could be receipt of another message, the passage of some amount of time, input from stdin, etc.  There are more Twisted docs on twisted.org that cover how to work with those other event sources.


On that page you linked to, if I try the check_server_certificate.py script, it fails immediately with an error that host.decode("utf-8") can't be done on a str. If I remove the .decode part, it says "BAD" for every site, including www.twistedmatrix.com

It sounds like someone has failed to maintain those examples properly, sadly.  These things look like they'd be worth filing a bug against Twisted for.  If you do that, you might get someone to fix them - and hopefully as a result show you how to fix TLS in your code.

Yes, of course I'd send messages when some event occurs. I was asking how to do the actual sending. There should be something in Client that I'd call in this case - something that is not connected or disconnected or authenticated. I managed to find a this example, which seems to intend to do what I want - but it has obviously never been tested, is buggy and doesn't work.

Regarding the TLS code, I managed to find this modified example, which basically disables all the checks (and warns you not to do this) - and it kinda works, in the sense that the server does receive my message, but at the end the connection is terminated unexpectedly by the server; dunno why.

You know what, forget it. I am sick and tired of this crap that is Twisted's lack of proper documentation. I started using it 7 years ago because a project of mine was based on a project that used it and it's a decision I've been regretting even since. Meanwhile, I figured out how to work around a problem in xmpppy that prevented it from working correctly from Twisted in some circumstances and will use that instead of Twisted.Words. It's easy to use, I'm familiar with it, and I won't have to bang my head onto poorly documented arcane code. Thanks for trying to help.

The Ignite Realtime community has a document that provides a minimal working example of a client implementation using the Twisted Words library, making it connect to a running Openfire server.
https://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/client-minimal-working-example-twistedwords.html
The example that is used there is copied here (but the document contains more information).
#!/usr/bin/python
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

"""
A very simple twisted xmpp-client (Jabber ID)

To run the script:
$ python xmpp_client.py <jid> <secret>
"""


import sys

from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet._sslverify import (ClientTLSOptions,
                                         OpenSSLCertificateOptions)
from twisted.names.srvconnect import SRVConnector
from twisted.words.xish import domish
from twisted.words.protocols.jabber import xmlstream, client
from twisted.words.protocols.jabber.jid import JID


class Client:
    def __init__(self, reactor, jid, secret, configurationForTLS):
        self.reactor = reactor
        f = client.XMPPClientFactory(jid, secret,
                                     configurationForTLS=configurationForTLS)
        f.addBootstrap(xmlstream.STREAM_CONNECTED_EVENT, self.connected)
        f.addBootstrap(xmlstream.STREAM_END_EVENT, self.disconnected)
        f.addBootstrap(xmlstream.STREAM_AUTHD_EVENT, self.authenticated)
        f.addBootstrap(xmlstream.INIT_FAILED_EVENT, self.init_failed)
        connector = SRVConnector(reactor, "xmpp-client", jid.host, f, defaultPort=5222)
        connector.connect()
        self.finished = Deferred()

    def rawDataIn(self, buf):
        print("RECV: %r" % buf)

    def rawDataOut(self, buf):
        print("SEND: %r" % buf)

    def connected(self, xs):
        print("Connected.")

        self.xmlstream = xs

        # Log all traffic
        xs.rawDataInFn = self.rawDataIn
        xs.rawDataOutFn = self.rawDataOut

    def disconnected(self, reason):
        print("Disconnected.")
        print(reason)

        self.finished.callback(None)

    def authenticated(self, xs):
        print("Authenticated.")

        presence = domish.Element((None, "presence"))
        xs.send(presence)

        self.reactor.callLater(5, xs.sendFooter)

    def init_failed(self, failure):
        print("Initialization failed.")
        print(failure)

        self.xmlstream.sendFooter()


def main(reactor, jid, secret):
    """
    Connect to the given Jabber ID and return a L{Deferred} which will be
    called back when the connection is over.

    @param reactor: The reactor to use for the connection.
    @param jid: A L{JID} to connect to.
    @param secret: A C{str}
    """
    configurationForTLS = ClientTLSOptions(JID(jid).host,
                                           OpenSSLCertificateOptions().getContext())
    return Client(reactor, JID(jid), secret,
                  configurationForTLS=configurationForTLS).finished


if __name__ == "__main__":
    react(main, sys.argv[1:])

